# change default location of table space files

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Can anyone tell how to

> change the default physical location of table space files  ?

in oracle.

Currently it is created under `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` folder.My database is oracle 11gr1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to the [`DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST` initialisation parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams050.htm) for [Oracle-managed files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/omf001.htm). You can check the current value with `show parameters db_create_file_dest` from SQL*Plus, or in the `v$parameters` view.

To change it:

```
alter system set db_create_file_dest = '/path/to/new/location';
```

But as always, be sure you know what you're changing and what impact it will (or might) have before doing anything.